# SSIS Connection Manager using service account

Tags: ssis

How do I specify my SSIS package to use a domain service account when deployed and called from an Agent Job?

The Connection Manager is set to use [Windows Authentication], so I think it is using my windows credentials during development. However I want the package to use a domain service account with a non-expiring password when running as a Job on SQL Server.

How can I do this? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: The package will be run by the agent log on as user.

Comment: Thank You! 

Now in my case the Job the "Run As:" = "SQL Server Agent Service Account". 

I am guessing that maps to the login:
 [NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT] which is in the SysAdmin role. 

Is that correct?

Comment: Your DBA should be able to tell you.

Answer (score 2):

You or your DBA should do the following on the SQL Server:

- Create a *SQL Credential* for a desired Domain Account.
- Create a *SQL Agent Proxy* of type *SSIS Package Execution* and bind it to the *Credential* created.
- On the SQL Job step - specify created *Proxy* in `Run As:` dropdown

These steps allows to run specified SSIS Package under account of the *SQL Credential*.
Here is a [good sample](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/) on how to set it up.

Comment: Thank you. Part of the problem is that I am a developer at a small company who has become the unofficial DBA, but I am still learning. I was able to have it run by changing the ownership to NTSERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. I plan to read up and learn how to do it the proxy way as you described.

Comment: @JohnW. added a link to a detailed example with screenshots of steps described above.